# Wrapfig on right of text leaves blank space beneath the figure

Tags: xetex, wrapfigure

I am writing a LaTeX document that contains a right figure that is wrapped by text. However, despite being at the end of a page, there is a blank space that spread throughout multiple pages, in my case, leaving half the page empty.

[image: blank space on my latex document]

The blank space continues way below. I am compiling the doc with XeLaTeX, using wrapfig and the doc type is memoir.

The code behind it is this code

```latex
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\textwidth/2}
    \label{fig:branch-policies}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth/2]{img/azure-branch-policies.png}
    \caption{Politiques de branche}
\end{wrapfigure}

Un grand avantage d'Azure DevOps est l'intégration entre ses différents services. Par exemple, lorsqu'on ajoute l'identifiant d'un work item dans un commit, ce dernier va lier automatiquement ledit work item au commit.

Un autre avantage est la posibilité de configurer des politiques pour une branche donnée. Lorsqu'une Pull Request sera créée pour cette branche, ladite PR ne pourra pas être validée tant que les politiques ont été remplies.

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Minimum number of reviewers}: le nombre minimum de paires requis pour valider la pull request.
    \item \textbf{Linked work items}: si la PR doit contenir des work items liés\footnote{Par exemple, en mentionnant l'identifiant d'un work item dans un commit}.
    \item \textbf{Comment resolution}: si les commentaires de la PR doivent être marqués comme "résolu" ou non.
    \item \textbf{Limit merge types}: limite les types de merge (par exemple: squash merge)
    \item \textbf{Automatically included reviewers}: liste des paires assignés à la pull request vers la branche.
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Les pull request}

Les pull request sont une fonctionnalité très importante. Lorsqu'une est créée, nous demandons aux autres membres de l'équipe de vérifier cette PR.
```

For the code, I have errors on the paragraph before the figure and some of the items of the itemize that says "Underfull \hbox". I have searched what that error meant and I have no idea what the link is to my problem.

Has anyone any clue on what could be going on ?

Thank you very much ! <3

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: Neither itemize nor \subsubsection play well with wrapfig.

Comment: The wrapfig documentation explicitly documents that it should not be used with lists. But also, after _any_ error do not look at the pdf except as a debugging aid, it is not intended to be usable. As you have not provided example code nor said what the error message is, no one can help with that

Comment: `\textwidth/2` is not, by default, valid syntax, and should be `0.5\textwidth` unless you are using packages that change this. Please always provide an example _document_ that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle weird enough this syntax also worked with /3, so I guess it's working. Imma try the other way too.

As for the error,

> For the code, I have errors on the paragraph before the figure and some of the items of the itemize that says "Underfull \hbox".

Comment: underfull box is a warning not an error, but you have not provided any code people can run to see the issue and test answers